# Formatting tables in powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In word, I have been creating a macro that formats an existing table. The dimension of the table can be anything. The formatting looks like this:

[image]

My VBA code in word looks like this:

```
Sub Makro7()
'
' Makro7 Makro
'
'
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdRow
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdColumn
    Selection.Range.Relocate wdRelocateDown
    Selection.Range.Relocate wdRelocateUp
    Selection.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
    Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 192
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdColumn, Extend:=True
    With Selection.ParagraphFormat
        .LeftIndent = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .RightIndent = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .SpaceBefore = 0
        .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
        .SpaceAfter = 0
        .SpaceAfterAuto = False
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
        .WidowControl = True
        .KeepWithNext = False
        .KeepTogether = False
        .PageBreakBefore = False
        .NoLineNumber = False
        .Hyphenation = True
        .FirstLineIndent = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText
        .CharacterUnitLeftIndent = 0
        .CharacterUnitRightIndent = 0
        .CharacterUnitFirstLineIndent = 0
        .LineUnitBefore = 0
        .LineUnitAfter = 0
        .MirrorIndents = False
        .TextboxTightWrap = wdTightNone
        .CollapsedByDefault = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Now, I need this function in Powerpoint too. Unfortunately I can't just copy this code to Powerpoint. I'm not that familiar with VBA in Powerpoint, and don't know how to proceed. I get an error if I use this code within Powerpoint.

Comment: You do realize that you can use Table Styles in Word, don't you? Just create a table style with that formatting and add it to your document template. Then you can scrap all that code.

Comment: PowerPoint lacks an easy way to create Table Styles but it can be done if you fancy hacking the xml. If you must use VBA then you need to realize that each cell of a table in PowerPoint is a `Shape`. So you set the border and background color on the shape and text formatting is applied to the shape's `.TextFrame.TextRange`. Formatting can only be successfully applied if each cell contains text, so you'll probably need to add some dummy text first then delete it once your code has finished. A web search for "format a PowerPoint table using VBA" will provide you with some pointers.

Comment: I do, but for this I must be using VBA. If I hack the xml, would I have to do that on every single PC using this template? This template is supposed to be used by many people, so all table formatting must be inside the powerpoint file.

Comment: You create the PPT table style by editing the xml in the template. You can find a guide to doing this [on John Korchok's site](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/08/xml-hacking-table-styles-complete/)

Comment: A table style created in a template will travel with that template to all users. You can also set it as a default, so anyone who inserts a table gets that style. Much easier and reliable than writing a macro. Timothy linked to the second of 2 articles, here's the first: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/07/xml-hacking-custom-table-styles/ And here's how to set table text: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/03/xml-hacking-default-table-text/

Comment: Hi John and Timothy, thanks for your responses. I have looked into the xml hacking now. Using the "Blank" table theme as a starting point (white essentially just has black borders), all I really need is to color the header row a custom red, while leaving the text white and bold. Can you point me in the direction of where in the tablestyles xml file I can change that? When i change the text color, it seems to change all the text of the table and not just the header. Thanks!